# How to get data from grid

Tags: grid, livecode

How to see the content in hilightedline in data-grid?

```
put the dgHilitedLine of group "DataGrid"  into theLine
   answer dgLine[theLine]
```

if the value of "theLine" is 5 then, How to get the text in the highlighted field in the grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
put the dgHilitedLines of group "Datagrid" into mylist
put the dgText of group "Datagrid" into myText
repeat for each item tItem in mylist
  put line tItem of myText & CR after myselctedlines
end repeat
answer myselctedlines
```

see http://livecode.wikia.com/wiki/Datagrid_API

Comment: Thanks MaxV. How to color a word in datagrid?. I need to color "Name" to red in group "DFT".

Comment: You could change the datagrid template or use some of the **general properties** showed   http://livecode.wikia.com/wiki/Datagrid_API

Comment: i just changed it to the html. Thanks @ MaxV